OpenAI API either does not answer question or I cannot find where the response is given
Problem Summary
I am trying to us OpenAI API to make a batch request to chatgtp 3.5 turbo using Google Colab. It seems to work fine but it only returns the prompt. It never answers the question with the 1000 max_new_token allowance.
I am following the instructions on https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/batch/getting-started
The goal
To get Chatgtp to evaluate a response generated by another AI.
Libraries and Data

    chatgtp_context = """Please act as an impartial...```
    prompt = '\n # Query:\nwhy are elementary particles structureless?\n # Answer:\n',
'response': 'Hello! Elementary particles are...If you have any other questions, please let me know!'},



    import openai

    import os

    from google.colab import userdata

    OPEN_API_KEY =os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = userdata.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')

    from google.colab import files
    uploaded = files.upload()

    Llama_2_7b_output_response = Llama_2_7b_700_output_response.Llama_2_7b_output_response


API Format

    openai_queries = {
        "custom_id": "request-1",
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/v1/chat/completions",
        "body": {
            "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0125",
            "messages": [
                {"role": "system", "content": chatgtp_context},
                {"role": "user", "content": Llama_2_7b_output_response}
            ],
            "max_new_tokens": 1000
        }
    }


** Note that "messages" is a list of dictionaries structured as the 'prompt' example.
API requires data to be in JSONL type file

    with open('batch.jsonl', 'w') as jsonl_file:
      jsonl_file.write(json.dumps(openai_queries))

    from openai import OpenAI
    client = OpenAI()
    batch_input_file = client.files.create(
      file=open("batch.jsonl", "rb"),
      purpose="batch"
    )


    batch_input_file_id = batch_input_file.id

Create request

    client.batches.create(
        input_file_id=batch_input_file_id,
        endpoint="/v1/chat/completions",
        completion_window="24h",
        metadata={
          "description": "nightly eval job"
        }
    )


Fetch response

    file_response = client.files.content(batch_input_file_id)
    print(file_response.text)



I have tried consulting OPENAI's manual for batching and asking ChatGTP. Looking throughout the internet has not yielded answers.
As far as I know, I am doing it according to the book by formatting the call as a list of dictionaries, changing it to a .jsonl file(.jsonl files have one dictionary on each new line.)

I discovered that my completed batches are cataloged on my OpenAI account. Which is great because I at least have my answers, but I still don't know how to get the answers with code.

Oh wow.
So the documentation says that when you are trying to retrieve the output, you code:
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
file_response = client.files.content("file-xyz")
print(file_response.text)
However, file-xyz is NOT OF THE ORIGINAL ID. Rather the output has its own, unique id, that DOES NOT EXIST until after the batch has been completed. Once it has completed, you can find it in the output of
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
file_response = client.files.content("file-abc")
print(file_response.text)
Where file-abc is the original id.

Oh wow. So the documentation says that when you are trying to retrieve the output, you code: from openai import OpenAI client = OpenAI() file_response = client.files.content("file-xyz") print(file_response.text)
However, file-xyz is NOT OF THE ORIGINAL ID. This id DOES NOT EXIST until after the batch has been completed. Once it has completed, you can find it in the output of from openai import OpenAI client = OpenAI() file_response = client.files.content("file-abc") print(file_response.text) Where file-abc is the original id.
